# Get a Buried xml int inside node using vBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

Evening all,
I have had some help here before and hope that you can help again.

Previously I was trying to extract two bits of information from the following xml - which I have tagged in the xml. From the help on these boards I have worked up this code that extracts this.

I have since needed to extract a third bit of information which corresponds to Data Item 2 - i.e. it's color but I've been trying to use the same method but keep getting an error saying object doesn't support this. I've done a lot of googling and testing before coming back but just can't get it to work. Any help/advice/solution would be really appreciated.

Working code for Data Item 1 and 2:

```
Sub ReadXML()
Call fnReadXMLByTags
End Sub
Function fnReadXMLByTags()
Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Clear
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\TestFile.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

Set slotNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/instrument/member/list/obj/member/string")
    
End Function
```

XML with Tags for Data 1,2 and data 3 which I can't reach

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<instrument>
   <string name="name" value="TEST" wide="true"/>   <!--I GETTHIS FIRST DATA 1-->
   <member name="slotvisuals">
      <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
      <list name="obj" type="obj">
         <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="882527840">
            <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
            <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
            <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
            <string name="text" value="CUSTOM ART1" wide="true"/>
            <string name="description" value="CUSTOM ART1 DESCRIPTION" wide="true"/>
            <int name="group" value="0"/>
         </obj>
         <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="45186017184">
            <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
            <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
            <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
            <string name="text" value="GROUP 2" wide="true"/>
            <string name="description" value="GROUP 2" wide="true"/>
            <int name="group" value="1"/>
         </obj>
         <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="882712304">
            <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
            <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
            <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
            <string name="text" value="GROUP 3" wide="true"/>
            <string name="description" value="GROUP 3" wide="true"/>
            <int name="group" value="2"/>
         </obj>
         <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="44402087248">
            <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
            <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
            <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
            <string name="text" value="GROUP 4" wide="true"/>
            <string name="description" value="GROUP 4" wide="true"/>
            <int name="group" value="3"/>
         </obj>
      </list>
   </member>
   <member name="slots">
      <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
      <list name="obj" type="obj">
         <obj class="PSoundSlot" ID="2271687808">
            <obj class="PSlotThruTrigger" name="remote" ID="2276282784">
               <int name="status" value="144"/>
               <int name="data1" value="0"/>
            </obj>
            <obj class="PSlotMidiAction" name="action" ID="2268706176">
               <int name="version" value="600"/>
               <member name="noteChanger">
                  <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
                  <list name="obj" type="obj">
                     <obj class="PSlotNoteChanger" ID="2277009712">
                        <int name="channel" value="-1"/>
                        <float name="velocityFact" value="1"/>
                        <float name="lengthFact" value="1"/>
                        <int name="minVelocity" value="0"/>
                        <int name="maxVelocity" value="127"/>
                        <int name="transpose" value="0"/>
                        <int name="minPitch" value="0"/>
                        <int name="maxPitch" value="127"/>
                     </obj>
                  </list>
               </member>
               <member name="midiMessages">
                  <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
               </member>
               <int name="channel" value="-1"/>
               <float name="velocityFact" value="1"/>
               <float name="lengthFact" value="1"/>
               <int name="minVelocity" value="0"/>
               <int name="maxVelocity" value="127"/>
               <int name="transpose" value="0"/>
               <int name="maxPitch" value="127"/>
               <int name="minPitch" value="0"/>
               <int name="key" value="-1"/>
            </obj>
            <member name="sv">
               <int name="ownership" value="2"/>
               <list name="obj" type="obj">
                  <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="909444640">
                     <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
                     <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
                     <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
                     <string name="text" value="CUSTOM ART1" wide="true"/>
                     <string name="description" value="CUSTOM ART1 DESCRIPTION" wide="true"/>
                     <int name="group" value="0"/>
                  </obj>
                  <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="43544745280">
                     <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
                     <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
                     <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
                     <string name="text" value="GROUP 2" wide="true"/>
                     <string name="description" value="GROUP 2" wide="true"/>
                     <int name="group" value="1"/>
                  </obj>
                  <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="44505641184">
                     <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
                     <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
                     <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
                     <string name="text" value="GROUP 3" wide="true"/>
                     <string name="description" value="GROUP 3" wide="true"/>
                     <int name="group" value="2"/>
                  </obj>
                  <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="44402092688">
                     <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
                     <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
                     <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
                     <string name="text" value="GROUP 4" wide="true"/>
                     <string name="description" value="GROUP 4" wide="true"/>
                     <int name="group" value="3"/>
                  </obj>
               </list>
            </member>
            <member name="name">
               <string name="s" value="THIS IS SLOT 1" wide="true"/> <!--AND THEN THIS -DATA2-->
            </member>
            <int name="color" value="1"/> <!--BUT I CANT GET THIS DATA3-->
         </obj>
      </list>
   </member>
   <member name="controller">
      <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
   </member>
</instrument>
```

Comment: What path did you try for that last item?

Comment: You're trying to access attributes (the items with `name=` and `value=`) as if they are elements. They're not. There is also no element or attribute within `obj` that is named `string` either. I'm not sure that you understand XML at all.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite - you are quite correct I don't understand xml as this is not my day job - I've fudged my way through to this point and want to learn but time is of an essence.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - your problem "DATA3" item is the last one in the second loop

```vb
Sub fnReadXMLByTags()
    Dim oxmlfile As Object, els, el
    
    Set oxmlfile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    oxmlfile.LoadXML ([A1]) 'loading XML from cell
    
    Set els = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/instrument/member/list/obj/member/string")
    Debug.Print els.Length
    For Each el In els
        Debug.Print el.getattribute("name"), el.getattribute("value")
    Next el
    
    Set els = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/instrument/member/list/obj/int")
    Debug.Print els.Length
    For Each el In els
        Debug.Print el.getattribute("name"), el.getattribute("value")
    Next el
    
End Sub
```

If you only want the `int` where `name = color` then you can use:

```vb
Set els = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/instrument/member/list/obj/int[@name=""color""]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I've tried this but `els.length` is returning as zero and so the loop won't fire?

Comment: Ignore that - I had a simple typo in the xml path